# Cannot install latest Mongdb

Tags: mongodb, linux-mint

My production Mongo database was hacked and all databases deleted. I now want to upgrade to the latest version of Mongo but am having extraordinary problems. Im on Linux Mint 17.1. Im following instructions here:

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
```

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I end up with error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I try next? As I said, my app is down since the hack and now I cannot even install Mongo...

Comment: Please share the output of running ``apt list --installed | grep mongo`` and ``more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | cat``

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix packages.

If that doesn't work, figure out if you need all 4 packages, mongodb-org-server might be the only one you really need.

Comment: Tried sudo apt-get install -f, still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can try running the following command with a specific version (3.0.15 in my case):

```
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes mongodb-org=3.0.15 mongodb-org-server=3.0.15 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.15 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.15 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.15
```